# Is there a way to use Shiny datatables to do calculations with formulas like excel?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, datatable, dt

I have searched online for uses of Shiny datatables, but nothing I have found so far allows me to use Shiny datatables with formulas embedded in the whole column in a way so that I can edit a variable, and the whole column changes?

It would look a bit like this:
Interest rates (variable): 0.5%

| Name | Base Debt | Debt w/ Interest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1000 | 1005 |
| Mary | 2000 | 2010 |

Where debt w/ interest would be calculated by Base Debt * 1+interest, and the interest rate would be a variable set separately.

Please do let me know if this has already been answered!

Answer (score 0):

That's me again 1 hour later... the inputs can be operated on with formulas in the server side like:

```
library(shiny)
library(xts)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("var", "Var",2),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("data")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$data <- renderTable({
    # VOL 20 error handling
    NA_rows <- which(tabl$Num1 == "#N/A")
    tabl$Num1[NA_rows] <- 1
    
    # Calculations
    tabl$'Num1 * Num2 * Var' <- tabl$Num1 * tabl$Num2 * input$var 
    tabl
  }, bordered=TRUE, digits=5)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```